# function doesnt give the appropriate output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, return

The following function seems to give the appropriate output but when I import the same function to the other component, the function just gives a blank output. I think there happens to be a problem with the return statement.
P.S: What I'm trying to make is an online judge where user can input their solution and then we will test their function with some test cases we have defined.

```
const javascriptRunner = (fileLocation, input) => {
  //judge functionality

  // let output = ''
  import(`../codes/${fileLocation}`).then((f) => {
    console.log(
      'output:',
      f.default(...input),
      'type:',
      typeof f.default(...input),
      'for input :',
      input
    )
    return f.default(...input)
  })
```

Comment: just put a `return` before your `import`

Comment: seems so weird to be using import inside of a function.

Comment: @AdityaParab but then the main functionality wont work.

Comment: @epascarello yeah ik, but then how do I import a file using dynamic filelocations? like my main goal is to create a file, then import it in the javascript runner component i mentioned above

Comment: By using fetch?

Comment: better yet, `fs.readFile` if not running in browser..

Comment: fs.readFile sounds okay, but another query i have is that the file i am reading has an "export default ..." at its end and I only want the thing it is exporting as default but using fs.readfile gives me the entire file content

Comment: @epascarello fetch did not work, can you give me an example of what you are trying to explain?

Comment: May be the resolution of the the path from `../codes/${fileLocation}` would be wrong. Try verifying this

Comment: The path is fine

Answer (score 0):

Your function is using a relative path

```
`../codes/${fileLocation}`
```

You might want to replace it by an absolute path, like so

```
`codes/${fileLocation}`
```

I said "might" because it is difficult to answer without seeing your project structure.
Take a look at this [LINK](https://medium.com/geekculture/making-life-easier-with-absolute-imports-react-in-javascript-and-typescript-bbdab8a8a3a1#:%7E:text=According%20to%20create%2Dreact%2Dapp,will%20already%20have%20a%20tsconfig.) to setup your absolute path root

Comment: I get what you're saying but that makes my code cleaner and doesn't solve the problem. :3